# Check the status of a Model index?

Tags: searchkick

I have a task that populates a model with records - until that is done and I call reindex the user can get `Searchkick::MissingIndexError` errors which I am rescuing.

I want to display a message to tell the user the update is process - how can I check if a Model needs a reindex called?

Answer (score 1):

Dug into the source code and found this:

```
irb(main):088:0> Searchkick::Index.new('index_name').exists?
=> false
```

Open to a better answer.

Comment: To find the index name use `.searchkick_index_name` like so:

Searchkick::Index.new(  MyClass.searchkick_index_name ).exists?